# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.number'

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have such error in `React Native` project,

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.number'

I have new import of `PropTypes` in all project. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.PropTypes` has been moved from react package to `prop-types` package, you're probably using an outdated third party component that havn't made the necessary updates.

Edit : if this error is from your PropTypes declaration you have to use `PropTypes.number` instead of `React.PropTypes.number`

Comment: And how to found it in the project? I have searched in all project for the old import of PropTypes  (import {PropTypes} from 'react';) and there was 0 matches, the same as 0 matches for  React.PropTypes.number.

Comment: You have to search in your node_modules too

Comment: But it may have different syntax with spaces... You should try to identify what module is wrong by removing imports until it works or maybe you can find it by reading the error.